# Why my selenium java code is throwing exceptions inconsistently?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I'm new to java and selenium, so forgive me if I missing something very obvious. So i have the following code where I'm trying to click a dropdown button and then click another button inside it.

```
public class DropDown {

    private static final String URL =  "https://www.browserstack.com/guide/handling-dropdown-in-selenium-without-select-class";
    private static final String BUTTON = "//*[@class='bstack-mm-nav']/div[2]/button";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get(URL);
        
        WebElement developerButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(BUTTON));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(10000));
        
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(developerButton)).click();
        
        WebElement buttonToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Support']"));
        
        buttonToClick.click();
    }

}
```

I'm using an explicit wait to wait until the `developerButton` button becomes clickable. When I run this code multiple times, sometimes it runs without exceptions, and other times it throws either a `TimeoutException` or `ElementNotInteractableException`.

Now my understanding is that, with the explicit wait, it should wait either till my button becomes clickable, or till the time period I have set with the wait method has been crossed, in which case it will throw a `TimeoutException`. But sometimes I'm also getting the `ElementNotInteractableException`, which in my understanding I should not be getting because the click() action on the `developerButton` should only be done after it becomes clickable. Can you please shed some light on this for me.
Now while writing this question, I tried running that a bunch of times, and now I'm only getting a `TimeOutException`. Generally what I want to understand is the cause of this inconsistency. Thank you.